# Are global atomic variable used inside TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet threadsafe?

Tags: delphi, indy

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Delphi Indy Server and ThreadSafe variables.

Lets say I want a simple counter of the number of "hits" to my Delphi Indy webserver.  So I declare a global integer

```
var: GlobalWebHits: Integer
```

And inside my handler for **TIdHttpServer.OnCommandGet** I increment it:

```
procedure MyWebServer.CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  GlobalWebHits := GlobalWebHits+1;
  .....
end;
```

It this implementation ok with regards to thread safety?  Is it possible that two threads try to update GlobalWebHits at exactly the same time?

Should the incrementing be wrapped in a Critical Section?

Comment: The term "atomic variable" assumes simple read or write operations; other operations always require some kind of synchronization (at least that is so for intel x86 or x64 CPU's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an atomic variable. Operations can be atomic, or not.

```
GlobalWebHits := GlobalWebHits+1;
```

This one is not atomic. It has separate read, modify and write stages.

You could use a critical section but it is simpler and more efficient to use an atomic operation:

```
AtomicIncrement(GlobalWebHits);
```

or

```
TInterlocked.Increment(GlobalWebHits);
```

or

```
InterlockedIncrement(GlobalWebHits);
```

depending on which Delphi version you use.

Comment: Thank you.  The last version (InterlockedIncrement) worked for me on Delphi2007.   Question: In my original implementation, what are the consequences if GlobalWebHits is "compromised" (i.e. two threads writing to it at same time)?  Would this just lead to one copy overwriting another?  Or could it have more systemic effects that could lead to server instability?

Comment: You get incorrect data. Thread A reads 0, increments, and then writes. During this time thread B reads 0, increments and then writes. The end result is that the variable holds 1 when it should hold 2. This is the classic canonical data race. Some data races are benign. This one I guess is not.

Comment: Thank you - great explanation.  It is just a logging counter and is not used in any important respect except for reporting.  So in this case it is benign.  But I was just curious if violations such as this can lead to system instability.

Comment: @MSchenkel: the problems typically begin when you need to rely on the data being written in other threads...